# Ubuntu/Apache/Flask - sub-subdomain?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, I’ve set up the new server with apache -> MOD WSGI.

The configuration of apache recommends that I create subdomains. How will that interact with the fact that this server is itself a subdomain (http://myproject.lab.myschool.edu) set up by our university IT folks.

Can I make a sub-subdomain, e.g. admin.myproject.lab.myschool.edu

Setting aside whether it’s a useful idea I am interested in technically whether its possible or what the effect would be to do this.

Comment: Do you have access to the domain DNS records? If not, you cannot create a resolvable subdomain. You can however not only change the hostname of your server with `hostnamectl -set-hostname` (if you have sudo or root access), you can also configure the subdomains to any subdomains you wish to use. Technically, yes, it is possible to configure a subdomain of your university URL, but if an A record is not added in the DNS root, the record will exist only on your server.

Comment: Thanks. So, what is the effect of configuring a subdomain in apache as they recommend on install? I guess I need to understand better what it means to define a subdomain in apache. (Again I can live a happy life not knowing this, I just want to fill in the blanks.) Maybe you have a link?